# Magento 2 - Reindexing generates SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: magento, indexing, magento2

- I imported products through the CSV import feature.
- The import went without any issues.
- All imported products are listed in admin panel.
- the problem is with indexing catalog_product_attribute only. The rest indexes reindex ok.

When I tried reindex the index (in console) to make them visible in the frontend store, I got SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation error:

*SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '8942-138-1-265' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `mag_catalog_product_index_eav_idx` (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?).....*

Please advice me what shall I do? Thanks!

Comment: Do you import at least into 2 stores?
The attribute with id= 138 is a multiselect?

Comment: I have the same problem. Only one store and in my case the attribute is indeed a multiselect. @Pete-jaworski: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem in my case. My attribute was of type `multiselect`. This means that Magento will split the string apart into separate ID's and create unique keys in the index-table for each option.

However... If you have duplicate values in your database (due to a failed import or some other reason), this error will be thrown.

In my case the `value` in my database was `227,15,227`, which has the value `227` 2 times, throwing the above error. Changing the value to `227,15` solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem description** : Issue is with `multiselect` filterable attributes only. Suppose if we save single value from `multiselect` options for pert. SKU then in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table value stored with comma separate(because as per `multselect` behaviour Magento storing data with comma separate).

***Solution*** :
Create cron file through which get all values of that attribute from  `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table and then using PHP explode using (,) comma and then make unique array and again update same value using `primary_key`.

Working for me.

Answer (score 0):

After the upgrade of the Magento software we need to reindex the data using the standard method by shell:

```sh
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If the reindex task produces the following error you'll need to fix the data in the product entity tables by this [script](https://gist.github.com/shinesoftware/9df5c706fd5c9161c36297b2509eba33).